# While loop performing more loops than instructed

Tags: python, while-loop

In this piece of code the iterations should stop at one position earlier than they do.

```py
k = 0
while 2^k < 5:
    k += 1
print(k)
```

I expect it to print '3' but it prints out '4'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`^` is the [bitwise XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) operator.  You probably meant `**` for exponentiation.

Answer (score 6):

In Python the `^` operator is bitwise exclusive-or - not exponentiation.  Use `**` for exponentiation.